# Как реализовать команду паузы для Discrod бота? Discord.Net, ffmpeg

Tags: c#, discord

Пишу Discord бота (используя библиотеку Discord.Net) с возможностью воспроизвести audio. Я смог заставить бота подключится и начать проигрывать audio файл, но совершенно нет идей как реализовать паузу с возможностью потом продолжить воспроизведение с момента на котором оно было остановлено.

Код реализации воспроизведения файла

```
public async Task SendAsync(IGuild guild)
    {
        IAudioClient audioClient;
        if (ConnectedChannels.TryGetValue(guild.Id, out audioClient))
        {
            string path = "D:/My Projects/Discord Bot/MyBot/books/001.mp3";
            using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(path))
            using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
            using (var discord = audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
            {
                try 
                {
                    AudioStreamChannels.TryAdd(guild.Id, discord);
                    await output.CopyToAsync(discord);
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    Stream discordStream;
                    if (AudioStreamChannels.TryRemove(guild.Id, out discordStream))
                    {
                        await discordStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        
    }
```

Как можно реализовать паузу?

Comment: Если это простые `Stream`, то в теории достаточно будет при паузе запомнить текущую позицию (`Position` наверно), а после возобновления, сдвинуть (при помощи `Seek()`) обратно на нужное место и уже потом `output.CopyToAsync(discord);`.

Comment: можно писать так `out Stream discordStream`, чтобы не объявлять заранее, на будущее пригодится